# % in my output using Unix, and weird characters as another output. C++

Tags: c++, unix, character, codelite

I have one two coding projects currently, both of which are giving me weird trouble that I just can't figure out. I've spent hours messing with every little thing to try and fix them and they just don't seem to work out.

The first is a simple program to step through a .txt file and assign values to the characters, adding to the totalvalue, which is printed. 'A'-'Z' are values 1-26, respectively, '-' is 0, and '.' is also 0. An example .txt file would be:

```
...............
..-............
.........A.....
..Z.........C..
```

The answer here would be 30. Initially I was getting "30%" as the output, and while messing with it to try and get rid of the random '%', I somehow screwed up my logic somewhere and now it is just outputting "0%" for every file. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int getValue(char indicator)
{
    int value;
    if (indicator = 'A')
    {
        value = 1;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'B')
    {
        value = 2;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'C')
    {
        value = 3;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'D')
    {
        value = 4;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'E')
    {
        value = 5;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'F')
    {
        value = 6;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'G')
    {
        value = 7;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'H')
    {
        value = 8;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'I')
    {
        value = 9;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'J')
    {
        value = 10;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'K')
    {
        value = 11;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'L')
    {
        value = 12;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'M')
    {
        value = 13;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'N')
    {
        value = 14;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'O')
    {
        value = 15;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'P')
    {
        value = 16;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'Q')
    {
        value = 17;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'R')
    {
        value = 18;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'S')
    {
        value = 19;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'T')
    {
        value = 20;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'U')
    {
        value = 21;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'V')
    {
        value = 22;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'W')
    {
        value = 23;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'X')
    {
        value = 24;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'Y')
    {
        value = 25;
    }
    else if (indicator = 'Z')
    {
        value = 26;
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    string filename;
    ifstream txtfile;
    char indicator;
    int currentvalue;
    int totalvalue = 0;
    cin >> filename;
    txtfile.open(filename.c_str());
    while(txtfile >> indicator)
    {
        if (indicator = '.')
        {
            currentvalue = 0;
        }
        else if (indicator = '-')
        {
            currentvalue = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentvalue = getValue(indicator);
        }
        totalvalue += currentvalue;
    }
    cout << totalvalue;
    return 0;
}
```

My second issue is possibly a bit more complicated. This program converts a decimal into binary. I'm only allowed to make my own functions and edit the dec2bin function. Everything else is off limits, including int main(). The comments in the code are all from my TAs to provide tips on making the dec2bin function. I have made the exponential function, as we are not allowed to add any extra #includes. I will first show my code and then show what the output looks like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isdecimal(string &input)
{
    // see bin2dec for description of how the below code works

    return input.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == string::npos;
}

void reverse(string &input) 
{
    int n = input.length();
    for (int k=0; k<n/2; k++) 
      swap(input[k], input[n-1-k]);
}

int exponential(int &exponent)
{
    int multiple = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
    {
        multiple *= 10;
    }
    return multiple;
}

string dec2bin(string &decstr)
{
    // convert string decstr to integer decval:
    // 1) reverse to obtain LSB-MSB digit order
    reverse(decstr);
    // 2) for each ascii digit, subtract '0' to 
    //    obtain integer value, multiply by 10^k
    //    and continually add result to decval
    unsigned int i;
    int addval = 0;
    int remainder = 0;
    int decval = 0;
    int currentval = 0;
    char binchar;
    string newstring = "";
    for (i = 0; i < decstr.size(); i++)
    {
        currentval = (decstr[i] - '0');
        addval = currentval * exponential(i);
        decval += addval;
    }
    // apply successive-halving
    while(decval > 0) {
        remainder = decval % 2;
        decval = decval / 2;
        binchar = remainder;
        newstring.push_back(binchar);
    }
    // reverse to restore MSB-LSB bit order
    reverse(newstring);
    return newstring;
}

int main()
{
    string decstr;
    while (cin >> decstr) {
        if (isdecimal(decstr) == false)
            cout << "input error\n";
        else
            cout << dec2bin(decstr) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Since I am not allowed to post images, I will describe what my output looks like. Regardless of the integer I input, it returns some combinations of whitespace and weird square smiley faces (I'm using CodeLite for this, in Unix it prints nothing.)

Thank you in advance to absolutely anyone who helps me. i am just stumped on this. Also, feel free to be as vague as possible. Just some pointers may help. I'm sure the first one is some small syntax error or something like that, but I simply cannot find it.

Comment: Asking at least 2 questions providing lengthy code samples: No, tThat's not suitable for a proper SO question!! TL;DR; sorry ...

Comment: For your first problem if you don't want to use another method like the answers try to initialize variable "value" to zero, and in your second problem you can use bitwise operators to convert decimal to binary.

Comment: I would lookup what operator== is

Comment: Please don't bundle multiple independent questions into one post. SO is a question-and-answer resource, not a help forum. While the difference may seem subtle, the significance is that the primary mission is to create a repository of questions and answers that will be useful for other readers in the future, as opposed to just helping individuals solve their problems. Bundling questions together doesn't fit the Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved your first problem, you were assigning indicator and not comparing it, so you would always get 0. Also, I tidied up a bit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int getValue(char indicator)
{
    int value = 0;
    switch(indicator)
    {
        case 'Z': value++;
        case 'Y': value++;
        case 'X': value++;
        case 'W': value++;
        case 'V': value++;
        case 'U': value++;
        case 'T': value++;
        case 'S': value++;
        case 'R': value++;
        case 'Q': value++;
        case 'P': value++;
        case 'O': value++;
        case 'N': value++;
        case 'M': value++;
        case 'L': value++;
        case 'K': value++;
        case 'J': value++;
        case 'I': value++;
        case 'H': value++;
        case 'G': value++;
        case 'F': value++;
        case 'E': value++;
        case 'D': value++;
        case 'C': value++;
        case 'B': value++;
        case 'A': value++;
                  break;
        default: value = 0;
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    string      filename;
    ifstream    txtfile;
    char        indicator;
    int         currentvalue,
                totalvalue = 0;

    cin >> filename;
    txtfile.open(filename.c_str());

    while(txtfile >> indicator)
    {
        if (indicator == '.') // = is for assignment, == is for comparison
            currentvalue = 0;
        else if (indicator == '-')
            currentvalue = 0;
        else
            currentvalue = getValue(indicator);
        totalvalue += currentvalue;
    }
    cout << totalvalue << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And I get 30 with your input:)

Comment: See, that's what is completely getting me. I copy pasted this into codelite, just to check (I'm using Unix to submit) and it's still giving me 0. I completely believe you got 30, mainly because I just can't find anything wrong with the code. Maybe it is somehow my file, but the grading script we are given is also getting a 0 out of the program, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I take that back, I am now getting 30 again, but the percent sign is still present. I cannot for the life of me figure that out.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Codelite may be formatting things differently, I've never used it, so I don't know, I tested this with g++.

Comment: Also main can just be this: `int main()
{
    string      filename;
    ifstream    txtfile;
    char        indicator;
    int         currentvalue,
                totalvalue = 0;
    
    cin >> filename;
    txtfile.open(filename.c_str());
    
    while(txtfile >> indicator)
    {
        currentvalue = getValue(indicator);
        totalvalue += currentvalue;
    }
    txtfile.close();
    cout << totalvalue << endl;
    return 0;
}`

Comment: Ah, I'm using g++ in both CodeLite and unix. PErhaps that is the issue, although that still boggles my mind. I am a beginner but this is a warmup lab, so I think I'd be able to at least spot the error somewhere. It compiles fine, and that's what confuses me most. It compiles perfectly, yet gives me a % at the end of the output in Unix, which makes the grescript my professor provides count the lab wrong.

Comment: Try including stdio.h and using `printf("%i\n", totalvalue);` and see if you still get the % sign instead of the cout line

Comment: I have no idea what that actually does, but it works. I'm going to go look that library up. Thank you for all your help. My final issue with this one, and maybe I need to go somewhere else for help on this, is that the script runs my program in Unix like so: ./program < ~directory/scriptfile. Now with the code you have helped me fix, if I use my own file in such a manner, I still get 0. Could this have something to do with cin?

Comment: I figured it out. When an input is given this way, Unix doesn't need an fstream. It takes the file as if it is cin. By getting rid of the string and fstream, I got all 100 test cases to work. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Ian do not forget to upvote this answer and mark it as accepted :) Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote, but I definitely accepted it! :)

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using an assignment `=` operator?

`main.c`

```
while(txtfile >> indicator)
{
  if (indicator = '.')
  {
     currentvalue = 0;
  }
  // SNIP!
}
```

Surely you meant this:

```
while(txtfile >> indicator)
{
  if (indicator == '.')
  {
     currentvalue = 0;
  }
  // SNIP!
}
```

Big difference between `=` and `==`, one is an assignment, the other is equality checking of the contents.

Comment: Ah, totally slipped my mind! Thanks for pointing that out. It's still throwing 0s at me though. But thank you regardless, stupid mistake of mine.